# How to apply a function to several columns listed in a vector in a function

Tags: r, function, multiple-columns

Within a function, I am trying to create an additional column to a data frame, which corresponds to the minimum of several other columns that are listed in the entry of the function.

A minimal data set would be:

```
C1 <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)
C2 <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)
C3 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
C4 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
Data <- data.frame(C1, C2, C3, C4)
```

If I want the minimum from C1, C2, and C4, outside a function, I would call:

```
Data$Min <- pmin(Data$C1, Data$C2, Data$C4)
```

Inside a function, however, I struggle and was only able to produce this:

```
min.col <- function(data, conditions){
                    data$Min <- pmin(data[[conditions]]) # [[ ]] is the wrong way to refer to the conditions, but I do not find how to

                    # After that, I go on here with my function based on the column data$Min but it is not relevant for the present problem.
}
```

To be called by:

```
min.col(data, conditions=c("C1", "C2", "C4"))
```

Anyone there to help? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These use only base R.

**1)** We can use `do.call("pmin", ...)` like this.

```
f <- function(data, cols) transform(data, min = do.call("pmin", data[cols]))
f(Data, c("C1", "C2", "C4"))
```

giving:

```
   C1 C2 C3 C4 min
1   1  0  0  0   0
2   0  1  1  0   0
3   1  1  0  0   0
4   1  1  0  1   1
5   0  0  0  0   0
6   0  1  0  0   0
7   1  0  1  0   0
8   1  0  1  1   0
9   0  0  1  0   0
10  0  1  0  0   0
11  0  1  1  0   0
12  1  1  1  1   1
13  1  0  0  0   0
14  0  1  0  0   0
15  0  0  1  0   0
```

**2)** or use `apply`

```
f2 <- function(data, cols) transform(data, min = apply(data[cols], 1, min))
f2(Data, c("C1", "C2", "C4"))
```

**3)** or `Reduce`

```
f3 <- function(data, cols) transform(data, min = Reduce(pmin, data[cols]))
f3(Data, c("C1", "C2", "C4"))
```

**4)** If data[cols] only has 0 and 1 cells then if we compute the number of 0's in a row then the minimum should be 1 if that sum is 0 and the minimum is 0 otherwise.  Note that 0 is regarded as FALSE and any other number is regarded as TRUE when coerced to logical so:

```
f4 <- function(data, cols) transform(data, min = +!rowSums(!data[cols]))
f4(Data, c("C1", "C2", "C4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this pretty quickly using some of the functions from the `tidyverse` packages. The key here is not to use quotation marks, wrap the columns in `vars`, and then use the triple bang `!!!` to separate and evaluate in the function.

```r
library(tidyverse)

min.col <- function(data, conditions){
  data %>%
    mutate(Min = pmin(!!!conditions))
}


min.col(Data, vars(C1, C2))
#>    C1 C2 C3 C4 Min
#> 1   1  0  0  0   0
#> 2   0  1  1  0   0
#> 3   1  1  0  0   1
#> 4   1  1  0  1   1
#> 5   0  0  0  0   0
#> 6   0  1  0  0   0
#> 7   1  0  1  0   0
#> 8   1  0  1  1   0
#> 9   0  0  1  0   0
#> 10  0  1  0  0   0
#> 11  0  1  1  0   0
#> 12  1  1  1  1   1
#> 13  1  0  0  0   0
#> 14  0  1  0  0   0
#> 15  0  0  1  0   0
```